# How do I map every item in an array to a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array and there are 40 numbers within the array. I want to assign every number in the array its own unique string. Just for example, index 0 would be " A " , index 1 would be " B" , Index 2 would be "C " . I hope that is clear enough. How can I map 40 items in the array to its own string? Thanks!

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: Can't you just convert the indexes into strings? They would be unique. Or you want the strings to contain only alphabetic characters? Be specific and also show your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.fromCharCode` along with `String#charCodeAt`.

```js
const arr = [0,1,2];
const res = arr.map(x => String.fromCharCode(x + "A".charCodeAt(0)));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I feel like the OP needs to spec what happens after 26 and show a little research